# Is there a way to add public group to unmanaged/managed package?

Tags: package

I have created a public group to give access on report folder. Now i created unmanaged package and added all the components but not able to add public group to the package.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Public groups and queues can't be packaged. You'll have to write some install steps/release notes to admins that install the app, suggesting how they can configure the security.

List of packageable items is in https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/226/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf pages 24-32 or

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_unmanaged_components.htm

Comment: Also consider consulting the [metadata coverage report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage).